# How does branching from the many-worlds interpretation come from the assumption of a universal wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, measurements, quantum-interpretations

In the many-worlds interpretation, the cut between the observed and the observer, the quantum and the classical is removed, and it logically follows that there can be a universal wavefunction. When something is measured, the observer is in a superposition of seeing the thing that is measured in different states. However, I could not understand how the process of measurement branches the universe into multiple in the many worlds interpretation, instead of just the observer being in a superposition. How does branching from the many-worlds interpretation come from the assumption of a universal wavefunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"However, I could not understand how the process of measurement branches the universe into multiple in the many worlds interpretation, instead of just the observer being in a superposition."*

You are correct. The Everett Interpretation (see [Everett's thesis](https://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/everett_phd.pdf)) does *not* talk about branching the universe - it only says the observer is in a superposition.

One of the popularisers of Everett's Interpretation (either Wheeler or DeWitt, I think) tried to explain it to the general public by saying that from the observer's point of view, it would look *as if* each outcome happened in a separate world. The superposed states are orthogonal, they don't interact, they evolve independently, so it is *as if* the universe had split into several parallel universes, with one possible outcome happening in each. This became more popularly known as the Many Worlds Interpretation.

The whole point of Everett's proposal was that you only needed plain unitary quantum mechanics. There was no faster-than-light wavefunction collapse. There's no classical/quantum division. The laws of physics are time-reversible, deterministic, local, realist. The problem with splitting universes is that it effectively re-introduces collapse by the back door - obvious questions like how fast the rip separating the universes propagates, what triggers a rip, what is its actual detailed mechanism, is the splitting of universes reversible, and so on reintroduce many of the problems Everett had got rid of.

'Many Worlds' is a useful analogy for imagining what it looks like to an observer from the inside, at a very introductory level. But the analogy quickly falls apart if you try to work at a deeper and more detailed level. The observer and observed enter an orthogonal superposition of joint states in each of which the observer part of the state is correlated with the state of the system observed.

Answer (score -1):

The many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics (MWI) claims that the whole of physical reality is a structure that looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes in some circumstances but includes a lot of other structure that is revealed by phenomena such as quantum interference and Bell correlations:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

In quantum mechanics without collapse if information about an observable is copied from one system to another that prevents interference between different values of that observable:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02092

Copying of information is common for macroscopic objects, e.g. - light reflecting from you and the objects you see copies information about those objects into the light. So for macroscopic objects there isn't much interference on the scale we can see and instances of those systems with different values for those large scale observables don't interfere and they don't interact much. As a result different versions of macroscopic objects tend to sort themselves into layers, each of which acts approximately like the universe as described by classical physics - parallel universes:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189